# detect a touch down event on UIImageView(s)

Tags: iphone

I placed 4 UIImageView on UIView and I named them

```
UIImageView myImg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];     
UIImageView myImg2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];     
UIImageView myImg3 = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; 
UIImageView myImg4 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

How can I tell the compiler that I have just touched down UIImageView 1 or UIImaveView 2. If I only can use UIImageView to do this task, not buttons at all. Please guide me about this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A stylish solution is to use the **UIGestureRecognizer** object:

in your **loadView** method (or anywhere you code the **UIImageView**(s) drawing...):

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    [anImageView setTag:0]; //Pay attention here!, Tag is used to distinguish between your UIImageView on the selector
    [anImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [anImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewDidTapped:)] autorelease];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [anImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [contentView addSubview:anImageView];
    [anImageView release];

    UIImageView *anotherImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 180, 100, 100)];
    [anotherImageView setTag:1]; //Pay attention here!, Tag is used to distinguish between your UIImageView on the selector
    [anotherImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [anotherImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewDidTapped:)] autorelease];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [anotherImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [contentView addSubview:anotherImageView];
    [anotherImageView release];
```

This is a simple **imageViewDidTapped:** sample method that you can use to distinguish between the two sample **UIImageView** objects above:

```
- (void)imageViewDidTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)aGesture {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)aGesture;

    UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView *)[tapGesture view];

    switch (tappedImageView.tag) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"UIImageView 1 was tapped");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"UIImageView 2 was tapped");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `tag` property for this. Give each image a unique `tag`, then use this information to determine which image was touched. For example, set the tags by

```
UIImageView myImg1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];     
myImg1.tag = 1;
```

and when you receive a touch for `img`, call

```
img.tag
```

to retrieve the tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [myImg1 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
        [myImg2 addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
        [singleFingerTap release];
```

And action method

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: but the question is still not answered, this will recognize the touch but not the exact image that is touched, this code needs some more modification.

Comment: hmm. Lets read the question - _How can I tell the compiler that I have just touched down UIImageView 1 or UIImaveView 2_. In my answer OP gets touch from UIImageView 1 **or** UIImageView 2

Comment: that's why we can use tags with image and based on those tags we can identify that, there are also several other ways as well, like i can have co-ordinates of imageview, etc...

Comment: A gesture recognizer can only be added to one view at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

       CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
   if(CGRectContainsPoint(myImg1.view.frame,touchLocation))
 {
NSLog(@" Image 1");
}
else if(CGRectCont..
```

**Note..the NSLog will be outputted if the point lies in more than one image view..**
in that case..check which image view is on top..