# facing issue for touch down event for UIImageView again

Tags: iphone

If My Story Board contains

```
   View      
     |_my UIIMageView 1 
     |
     |_my UIImageView 2
```

I can handle the touch down event by following the solution at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976478/detect-a-touch-down-event-on-uiimageviews)

However, if my Story Board is changed to

```
   Scroll View      
     |_my UIIMageView 1 
     |
     |_my UIImageView 2
```

Now I can not detect the touch down event on one of these UIImageView...
Please help me on this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *touch;

    UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];
    anImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iad.png"];
    [anImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    anImageView.tag = 1001 ;

    touch = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(test)] autorelease];
    touch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [anImageView addGestureRecognizer:touch];
    [scrollView addSubview:anImageView];
    [anImageView release];

- (void) test:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

     UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;

     switch (imageView.tag)
     {
        case 1001: 
         // your code
        break;

        case 1002:
         // your code
         break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I just give it a try and it did work. Thanks for that. By the way. what is the difference if we use **-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {....}**

Comment: if i have 2 UIImageView.. how can i tell which one I have just touched down then. Are there any ways tell **test** method such that :"this is UIImageView number 3, so do this.....blabla or this is UIImageVIew number 2, please do this...."

Comment: @tonytran: check updated code in test method. you need to assign tag to your image views.

Comment: what I did is - 
    **[myImgView1 addGestureRecognizer:touch];**
    **[myImgView2 addGestureRecognizer:touch];**
    myImgView1.tag = 8 ;
    myImgView2.tag = 9 ;

I run it but I could not detect the UIImageView. Have I did done something wrong then...Just let you know all UIScrollView and UIImageView1 and UIImageView2 are added in the story board

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7001/discussion-between-tonytran-and-maulik)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, but you should think about using UIButtons instead of UIImageViews.

Each UIButton have an UIImageView inside plus all the touch events with it.

Comment: the problem I dont want to switch to UIButton is whenever I click on the button, it will be highlighted and I dont know how to avoid this.Please show me if you have any ideas

Comment: You can always put the same image for the normal state and for the highlighted state!