# How to create a bus seat plan ? what would be the best technique to design it in ios objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, uicollectionview

requirements are : using ui collection view or set of buttons that have different tags ?
web service is: http://api.bookme.pk/REST/API/rest_api.php?seats_info&api_key=6b3be4e8ff318561bc1efd9a0f604f29&service_id=1&time_id=18&date=2014-08-20
so ; when this web service is called on view did load ; i want to display total number of seats and then reserved seats and available seats of different colours.

How it will be possible to make it completely dynamic that at view did load it shows a bus seats view ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a UIView [or scroll view if you want to pinch, zoom, swipe] with a map of your bus deck.

With the provided json, you can "draw" the sits on a grid [a colour circle], you will have to give each sit an X and Y position,

so for example, seat 1 would be x = 10 , y = 10.

Have different colours for male or female , reserved,

this would be easier than collection view, but you can use it if you most, just have a custom layout and change the cell items colours.

Comment: Thanks mako ; but it I am not able to understand what do you mean by "map" for bus and how I shall create buttons on different position

Comment: http://www.berryscoaches.co.uk/img/seating.gif you can draw on top of the uiview, for touch, instead of buttons, intercept touch on view, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976478/detect-a-touch-down-event-on-uiimageviews

Comment: Thanks mako it was very useful; but Need also more easy way as I am new to ios and do not have sound knowledge of ios .Thanks again